# if url is equal to radio button value, then check radio button

Tags: jquery

I have 4 radio button each with a different url value.

I have created this script with jQuery to redirect the browser to the radio button value when checked:

jQuery:

```
jQuery('#searchfilter input').click(function () {
   if (jQuery('#searchfilter input').is(':checked')) {
      var value = jQuery(this).attr('value');
      window.location.href = value;
   }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="searchfilter">
   <div class="radio">
      <label>
         <input type="radio" value="url1" name="filter">URL1
      </label>
   </div>
   <div class="radio">
      <label>
         <input type="radio" value="url2" name="filter">URL2
      </label>
   </div>
   <div class="radio">
      <label>
         <input type="radio" value="url3" name="filter">URL3
      </label>
   </div>
   <div class="radio">
      <label>
         <input type="radio" value="url4" name="filter">URL4
      </label>
   </div>                 
</div>
```

The newly loaded page contains the same four radio buttons. I would like to put a check in the radio button which has the same value as the url. In other words, I'd like the last radio button checked to remain checked.

Is there an lean and efficient way to do this in jQuery without having to run four ifs and set up four variables for the url values?

Comment: A fiddle would be better: jsFiddle.net

Comment: What is your back end? If you are running PHP I would suggest dynamically setting the button value on page load. Otherwise of course this can also be achieved with JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will do trick:

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
       $('#searchfilter input').each(function (){
          if($(this).val()==window.location.href){
            $(this).attr("checked","true");
          }
       }); 
})
```

here a working  [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/p2rdR/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps - it would loop through all the radio buttons on your form and you are then left with one if statement.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('input[type=radio]').each(function() {
           if ($(this).prop('value') == window.location))
           {
              $(this).prop('checked', true)
           }
       });
 });
```